# transition causes views to change from black to clear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimationtransition

I am using the following code to pop a navigation controller from one view controller to a second.

```
-(void)viewProfile :(UIButton *)sender{

NSMutableArray *allViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];
ProfileViewController *newVC = [[ProfileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProfileViewController" bundle:nil];
[allViewControllers insertObject:newVC atIndex:0];
self.navigationController.viewControllers = allViewControllers;
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.2f;
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition
                                            forKey:kCATransition];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

}

The code works quite well. The one flaw is on the transition the view controller coming or ProfileViewController appears black. Then over the course of the animation it brightens to the default value, meanwhile the view controller calling this function becomes black.

How do I prevent this shading and just have the views always have their default colour throughout the transition?

Comment: Check background color for ProfileViewController.view in your storyboard/xib

Comment: i tried '    newVC.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
'
but it didn't make any changes